# Alloy analyzer crash with mac (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, alloy

I have a problem when I try to open an Alloy analyzer apps since I upgraded my OSX to El Capitan version. It shows me this message "it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows". Can anyone help..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this -- it works fine under El Capitan for me. Can you tell us what version of Alloy you're running? Are you sure it's not a Java version issue?

Comment: Thanks Danial, you are right. The problem was Java version.